# Mininet ospf6d IPv6 Quagga

Tags: mininet, quagga

enjoy my English.
I am running a topology of the image in Mininet with Ipv6, for this I use Quagga through ospf6d.
But I can't get routing, I've done the proper script, but I feel like it's part of the configuration that makes it not work.

[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNHge.png)

```
r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth1 inet6 add 2001:1::12/64')
r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth1 inet6 add 2001:1::21/64')
r1.cmd('ifconfig r1-eth2 inet6 add 1::10/64')
h1.cmd('ifconfig h1-eth0 inet6 add 1::1/96')
h1.cmd('route -6 add default gw 1::10 dev h1-eth0')  # add ipv6 default route for h1
r2.cmd('ifconfig r2-eth2 inet6 add 2::20/64')
h2.cmd('ifconfig h2-eth0 inet6 add 2::2/64')
h2.cmd('route -6 add default gw 2::20 dev h2-eth0')  # add ipv6 default route for h2

info('starting zebra and ospfd service:\n')

r1.cmd('zebra -f /usr/local/etc/r1zebra.conf -d -z ~/Desktop/Apis/r1zebra.api -i ~/Desktop/Apis/r1zebra.interface')
time.sleep(1)  # time for zebra to create api socket
r2.cmd('zebra -f /usr/local/etc/r2zebra.conf -d -z ~/Desktop/Apis/r2zebra.api -i ~/Desktop/Apis/r2zebra.interface')
r1.cmd('ospfd -f /usr/local/etc/r1ospfd.conf -d -z ~/Desktop/Apis/r1zebra.api -i ~/Desktop/Apis/r1ospfd.interface')
r2.cmd('ospfd -f /usr/local/etc/r2ospfd.conf -d -z ~/Desktop/Apis/r2zebra.api -i ~/Desktop/Apis/r2ospfd.interface')

r1.cmd('ospf6d -f /usr/local/etc/r1ospf6d.conf -d -z ~/Desktop/Apis/r1zebra.api -i ~/Desktop/Apis/r1ospf6d.interface')
r2.cmd('ospf6d -f /usr/local/etc/r2ospf6d.conf -d -z ~/Desktop/Apis/r2zebra.api -i ~/Desktop/Apis/r2ospf6d.interface'
```

This is the sequence of OPv6 assignment and configuration.
To test and performed test with ipv4 where it runs normal, but in ipv6 I only have connectivity between h1-eth0 - r1-eth1 and h2-eth0 - r2-eth1, but there is no extreme connectivity nor of r1-eth1 - r2 -eth1.
When executing, the sockets should be created for me, however, only the ones from ospfd for ipv4 are created and not those from ospf6d for ipv6.
Someone who has worked with this, please help me.

Comment: did you ever solve this?